# Confused about *storage-class 'Glacier' use by S3* and *S3-Glacier' service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

Still confused about storage-class 'Glacier' use by S3 and S3-Glacier' service.
What's their difference and how about their upload and retrieve?

See a example question below.

You’re researching third-party backup solutions to backup 10 TB of data nightly to Amazon S3. File restores won’t be needed often, but when they are, they’ll need to be available in under five minutes. Your analysis shows that you will exceed your budget for backup storage and you need to find a way to reduce the estimated monthly costs. How should you modify the solution to achieve the cost reduction needed?

1. Create an S3 lifecycle rule to move the data immediately to Amazon
   S3 Glacier
2. Choose a third-party backup solution that writes directly to the
   Amazon S3 Glacier API
3. Choose a third-party backup solution that leverages AWS Storage
   Gateway to write data to Amazon S3 Glacier.

Why option 2 is correct and how about option 1 and option 3? Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Glaicer is a storage class under the S3 service. Glacier is used for archiving data. Glacier and Glacier Deep Archive have a longer retrival time than the other S3 storage tiers (Standard, Standard-IA, One Zone-IA), but also cost significantly cheaper.

This looks like a certification question, CSA - Associate, maybe? You may have forgotten to provide the fourth answer choice.

1. You cannot move data to Glacier immediately using a lifecycle policy. You can set it to 0 days but it still takes time to make the move.
2. You do not need third party software to write to the AWS APIs, you can use the CLI and SDKS
3. This maybe the answer because, using a third-party piece of software that is able to take care of some of the overhead involved in getting a Storage Gateway File Gateway up and running, and configured to store data to Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive is easier.

Typically, "third-party" is not the answer in certification exam questions.